# Scrolling in jqPlot

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jqplot

I am using `jqPlot` to show candlestick chart and the data is from `XML`.
I retrieve data from `XML` and put it into an array and then `jqPlot` creates a candlestick chart from that.
But the `XML` file contains lots of data so in the chart values are overlapping (with fixed width).

Is it possible to make a graph of lets say 10% of data and place a scrollbar and on every tick of scrollbar we rebuild graph with next data or there already exists such functionality of scrolling of graph/chart in `jqPlot`.

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to load `XML` at once, but not give the data at once to that `jqPlot` chart. Just make sure you are passing part of the data to `jqPlot`. Once you assign data to chart then go for the scrolling of data using `jQuery` or something like scroller code.
Whenever you scroll on this try to refresh or regenrate the chart by only the selected data.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can try Jonathan Cook's jqplot.annotatedTimeline.js available from the following URL:

https://bitbucket.org/j5bot/jqplot/downloads

You can see its features in action from:

http://screencast.com/t/mHY5eUV99XaT

Although I haven't tried this plugin yet it looks very good!